# Python - how can I address an array along a given axis?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a python script that is reading slices from a 3D array, like this:

```
def get_from_array(axis, start, end, array):
    if axis == 0:
        slice = array[start:end, :, :]
    elif axis == 1:
        slice = array[:, start:end, :]
    elif axis == 2:
        slice = array[:, :, start:end]
    return slice
```

I can't help but think there must be a better way of doing this! Any suggestions?

S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
idx = [slice(None)] * array.ndim
idx[axis] = slice(start, end)
myslice = array[tuple(idx)]
```

Comment: You only need to have `slice` objects for the first `axis+1` indices, the trailing `:` are added by default if missing, i.e. `idx = (slice(None),) * axis + (slice(start, end),)` will do the same as your `ndim` long list.

Comment: I think a slice object was exactly what I was looking for, even if I didn't know it! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `np.take`. Then you can do it in one line more naturally.

```
a.take(np.arange(start,end), axis=axis)
```

Notes:

- it won't accept the standard `:` slice notation but replace that with `range`
- It returns a copy, not a view

For example:

```
In [135]: a = np.arange(3*3*3).reshape(3,3,3)

In [136]: a.take(np.arange(1,2), axis=1)
Out[136]: 
array([[[ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[12, 13, 14]],

       [[21, 22, 23]]])
```